# If all "async Task Method()" calls return Task.FromResult() - does that execute synchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, blazor-server-side, bunit

If all `async Task Method()` calls return `Task.FromResult()` - does that execute synchronously?

I am asking this in the context of writing bUnit tests for my Blazor server app.

A big issue for bUnit is you need the rendering to complete before asserting content in the rendered page.

My `async Task OnInitializedAsync()` call a lot of async services. For the unit tests I have mock services and ever service method returns a `Task.FromResult()` of static data.

In this case, when inside the method I have:

```
_organization = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Does it build up a task an return immediately? Or does it see that the task is completed, assign the value, and continue executing?

In other words, for the test case, where there is no true async activity, does it execute synchronously and `OnInitializedAsync()` returns a `Task` that is completed?

Comment: To answer this question yourself, collect the Task and immediately call Task.IsCompleted without awaiting it.

Comment: @Joshua Unfortunately this is all being called from Blazor so I can't do that. I can verify it works for a simple test I did, but I ask in case there's nuance to what occurs. thanks

Comment: Incidentally, if it works for a simple test it works in the whole application. Either it was going to generate a definite synchronous answer or it was going to generate a deferred synchronous answer via scheduling a task that completes immediately when executed.

Comment: @Joshua 99% of the time I agree with you. But over the years I have occasionally hit situations where there are weird rarely hit exceptions that bite you in the ass at the worst possible time. I follow Andy Grove's mantra - Only the Paranoid Survive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will expand a little with my answer before I talk about bUnit and will also go into simple examples of what @guru-stron wrote.
For beginners, we have to explore the state machine of `async` at least to a very small degree.

### Scenario 1

That is in @guru-stron example the first one.

```cs
var myTask = MyTask();
Console.WriteLine("In between Something");
await myTask;

async Task MyTask()
{
   await InnerMyTask();
   Console.WriteLine("In MyTask");
}

async Task InnerMyTask()
{
   await Task.Delay(1); // Or any async operation like going to a DB
   Console.WriteLine("In InnerMyTask");
}
```

This will result to:

```
In between Something
In InnerMyTask
In MyTask
```

In regards of this ominous state-machine. Think of "await" as a method to slice your method into smaller methods. For each "await" you have one method that has the content from the last await (or beginning) to the current await.
Now if you await something and you spin up the Task - you give back control to the caller. You do this process for each caller in the chain that also uses "await". If you don't await (like in my given example the first calling function) then you keep the control flow inside that methods until `await` gets called. Once that `await` is hit your Task tries to continue (there is a lot more involved, but let's try to keep it simple). Now the most inner `Task` is completed (the one with `Task.Delay(1)`) - therefore we continue "like a synchronous function".

So as we don't directly await in the most outer function - we have "In between Something" and then the Console.WriteLine from the most inner and so on.

The Blazor Renderer, on which bUnits Renderer ultimately is based on, behaves like that. It is literally like the most outer function. So it "sees" `OnInitializedAsync` for example. If `OnInitializedAsync` goes to a db asynchronously then exactly that process I describes kicks in - therefore the renderer is "done" even though there will be future work.

### Scneario 2

Now if we take the example above, but directly return a completed Task:

```cs
var myTask = MyTask();
Console.WriteLine("In between Something");
await myTask;

async Task MyTask()
{
   await InnerMyTask();
   Console.WriteLine("In MyTask");
}

async Task InnerMyTask()
{
   await Task.CompletedTask; // Mocked our DB call
   Console.WriteLine("In InnerMyTask");
}
```

we get this:

```
In InnerMyTask
In MyTask
In between Something
```

I hope now that makes sense, as we never "give back" control to the caller! There "is nothing to await" (simplified).

So if you have completed Tasks inside `OnInitializedAsync` and friends, everything behaves synchronously.

Answer (score 2):

If task is not "truly" async or is completed then code after awaiting it will be executed synchronously. In short - in case of "chained" `await`'s everything before first `await` for "truly async" method (i.e. one which actually yields the control) will be executed synchronously:

```
// this will start a task but will not block to wait for delay
var task = First();
Console.WriteLine("Task started but not blocked");
await task;
Console.WriteLine("After root await");

async Task First()
{
    Console.WriteLine("First");
    await Second();
    Console.WriteLine("After First");
}

async Task Second()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Second");
    await Third();
    Console.WriteLine("After Second");
}

async Task Third()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Third");
    await Task.Delay(100);
    Console.WriteLine("After Third");
}
```

And you will see that all 3 `Console.WriteLine(number)` (which simulate sync/CPU-bound work in this case, you can sprinkle some `Thread.Sleep`'s if you want in addition) statements will be executed before the "Task started..." one but everything else will be executed after ([demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSCsA3OugPSnbAAWAlgM7YDuNANi9ncAIZjDZeUudANbYARhD7M22KAHs+YlnIDGo4HKZcafAGZyw2ACYBTFlwCe6AG49BI7AF5sAMRphOACgCUxDEgBOTwAiOAA2Dm5eEyNxSVkFcWU1GODfdDgA+2E/PCDggEFdYBNDMDlEzLS/DIAOXAi3D2AfdABvdGwu3ECQps5qzu7M7ABlExU5KCMfP26e/KKSw37gQbQAXxIMevCxiamZ73ahrryQ8cnp9fmRgBVaMCO54d7C4tL9q6N1rbQ6hrYB7uI4nNC3N7Ap43YZZcIAOgAImZLJ4kJhMOlwa9Fh9DFCfliNkA==)):

```
First
Second
Third
Task started but not blocked
After Third
After Second
After First
After root await
```

Now if we switch the "truly async" `await Task.Delay(100);` with a not actually async one (for example `Task.CompletedTask`):

```
async Task Third()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Third");
    await Task.CompletedTask; // not actually async, does not return control to the caller
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine("After Second");
}
```

The output will change significantly ([demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AKgBZgCmAhgCYCWUA5gNzpa5ICsza6A9D9sGI0AztgDuNADaTsw4BTDBsFARWEBrbACMISidOxQA9kq2SjAY03Aj4ijSUAzI2GxUykigE90ANwWqGtgAvNgAYjRgcgAUAJRceACc0QBEcABssvKKZFTauoYm2uZWuSnxLImB6glIySkAgo7AZK5gRkVwieVcLAAcuJkRUcBx6ADe6NjTbPXDcj1TM13YAMpkFkZQVHFcM7OpTS2u88CLaAC+6P2DaxtbO7ETS9NJqeub2+f7KySRj3tlnVDs1WndPlRzlduBgBhlsH8wI9nmgfsCUojIRVUcsqhl8ABhIwAWwADpIyC0qBlGNg+IUlBQLMAIBRpF5cH0ADRuIxkUTGJRwADs2E+wHaMhsAmIZDFbIpYHQAEgSORqPhVhSyKTokhMJhsWj6kcwZioUA===)):

```
First
Second
Third
After Third
After Second
After First
Task started but not blocked
After await
```

As you see all the root "work" simulated with corresponding write statements was completed **after** the async call chain (we can even remove `await task;` this will not change the result).

Original code for completeness:

```
async Task TestTask(Func<Task> factory)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before task");
    var t = factory();
    Console.WriteLine("Task created");
    await t;
    Console.WriteLine("After awaiting task");
}

// not actually async:
await TestTask(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("    before await");
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    Console.WriteLine("    after await");
});

Console.WriteLine("---------------");

// truly async
await TestTask(async () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("    before await");
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine("   after await");
});
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Before task
    before await
    after await
Task created
After awaiting task
---------------
Before task
    before await
Task created
   after await
After awaiting task
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm lost. Where/when/how are each of these being called? What is factory? And for the output, I assume the "before/after await" are paired with the 2nd then 3rd `TestTask`? And more importantly, is there any exception to this or by definition will this always be synchronous (the no Task.Yield() case)? TIA

Comment: It's an accurate answer but it's nearly beyond my comprehension and I know how async works. OP doesn't. I don't see how he's expected to understand it.

Comment: @DavidThielen 1) Where/when/how are each of these being called - `await TestTask` are the calls, `async Task TestTask(Func<Task> factory)` at the start is just a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) 2) What is factory - just a function returning a `Task` (i.e. task is created and started when the factory function is invoked - `factory()`) 3) yes, when awaiting a completed or not "truly async" (i.e. one which does not yield control to the caller) function then it will be executed synchronously.

Comment: @DavidThielen Updated answer a bit, hope it will make it more clear.

Comment: @Joshua Thank you, I see your point. Though I used this or similar code to explain the concept several times (and as far as I can tell was successful =). Tried to simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

> If all `async Task Method()` calls return `Task.FromResult()` - does that execute synchronously?

Yes. The continuation after the `await` of a completed task runs synchronously, on the same thread as the code before the `await`.

```
await Task.FromResult(0); // Continues synchronously
```

This happens for any number of `await`s. The `for` loop below runs synchronously as well.

```
// All this runs synchronously
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    await Task.FromResult(i);
}
```

The .NET `async` state machine uses a scheduler to schedule the continuation asynchronously only when it finds an awaitable with the property [`TaskAwaiter.IsCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.iscompleted) having the value `false`. Otherwise it just runs the continuation synchronously.